# How to determine if the specific time is between given range?

Tags: java

Problem: I have a list containg hours, for example:
08:15:00
08:45:00
09:00:00
12:00:00
...
application is allowing user to make an appointment for a specific hour let'say: 8:15:00, each meeting takes half an hour.

Question: How to determine if there is a slot needed for appointment like this? I know that Calendar class have methods before() nad after(), but it doesn'solve my problem. I mean if there is appointment at 12:00 and another one at 12:00, how to prevent before making another one at 12:15?

edit:

I've tried using methods I mentioned before, like:

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance(); // for example 12:00:00
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance(); // for exmaple 12:30:00
Calendar userTime = Calendar.getInstance(); // time to test: 12:15:00

if(user.after(cal1)&& user.before(cal2)){
... // do sth
}
```

Comment: I've tried using methods I mentioned before, like:
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance(); // for example 12:00:00
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance(); // for exmaple 12:30:00
Calendar userTime = Calendar.getInstance(); // time to test: 12:15:00

if(user.after(cal1)&& user.before(cal2)){
... // do sth
}

Comment: try throwing some code up, to work with.  People try to show you how to improve your code here, not just give you code to cut and paste without learning.

Comment: I don't need code, so no worries :), I think [ I know ] I'm missing some stupid detail. Just need a tip from You :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the date to check is between the two provided:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
Date before = sdf.parse("07/05/2012 08:00");
Date after = sdf.parse("07/05/2012 08:30");
Date toCheck = sdf.parse("07/05/2012 08:15");
//is toCheck between the two?
boolean isAvailable = (before.getTime() < toCheck.getTime()) && after.getTime() > toCheck.getTime();
```

To book for a determinate hour, I would do a class with two dates and a method to check this:

```
public class Appointment{

 private Date start;
 private Date end;

 public boolean isBetween(Date toCheck){....}

}
```

Then you can simply do an `Schedule` class extending `ArrayList`, adding a method `isDateAvailable(Date toCheck)`, iterating the list of Appointments and checking that there is no one conflicting.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have some kind of appointment class with either a start timestamp and a duration or a start time and an end time.  Then when adding new appointments to the schedule, check that the appointment with the start time before the new appointment doesn't run over the start time of the proposed new appointment.

Answer (score 1):

Well how you would do it specifically depends on how you are storing your data, format, etc., but generally what you would do is simply check if there is an appointment for any time between the requested time to the requested time + requested length.

```
// Example (using int time(1 = 1 minute), assuming that appointments can only be at 15min intervals)
boolean isHalfHourTimeSlotAvaliable(int time) {
    for (int i = 0; i < appointments.size(); i++) {
        if (appointments.get(i).time == time || appointments.get(i).time == time + 15) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```